# Writing messages to Application Event Log

Tags: c#, event-viewer

I am running into an issue writing events to the Windows Event Log.  I have looked through the posts and I think I am doing it correctly, but I still get the following error in the event viewer:

**the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table**

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am missing?

I am having the event source created in the WIX installer:

```
<Fragment>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK35"/>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20"/>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20INSTALLROOTDIR"/>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20INSTALLROOTDIR64" />

    <Component Id='EventSource'
               Directory='INSTALLDIR'
               Guid='F382AAC5-F7C5-46A4-95CF-EA7724DXXXXX' >
        <Condition>ALLUSERS</Condition>
        <?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
            <util:EventSource Log='Application'
                    Name='MySource'
                    EventMessageFile='[NETFRAMEWORK20INSTALLROOTDIR64]EventLogMessages.dll'
                    KeyPath='yes' />
        <?else ?>
            <util:EventSource Log='Application'
                    Name='MySource'
                    EventMessageFile='[NETFRAMEWORK20INSTALLROOTDIR]EventLogMessages.dll'
                    KeyPath='yes' />
        <?endif ?>
    </Component>
</Fragment>
```

And here is my C# code where I write to the Event Log:

```
public class Log
{
    private const string EventSource = "MySource";
    private const string EventLog = "Application";
    private static EventLog _logger = null;

    private static void InitLogger()
    {
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(EventSource))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(EventSource, EventLog);
        }
        _logger = new EventLog() { Source = EventSource, Log = EventLog };
    }

    public static void Write(EventLogEntryType entryType, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        string entry = _Format(format, args);

        try
        {
            if (_logger == null)
                InitLogger();
            _logger.WriteEntry(entry, entryType, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Tracer.Misc.Error("Could not write to event log: {0}", entry);
        }

    }

    private static string _Format(string format, object[] args)
    {
        if ((args == null) || (args.Length == 0))
            return format;

        try
        {
            return String.Format(format, args);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return format + " [Format Exception:" + e.Message + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is Tracer.Misc.Error ? full source sample ?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out my issue.  The code I have is fine.  The problem is with the name of the EventSource I was using.  The event source contained spaces and dashes.  When I removed those it worked.

I.E. going from 'My Event-Source' to 'MyEventSource'

Comment: This fixed my issue as well. It's not stated anywhere obvious that event sources can't have spaces, and even some of the event sources in the Event Viewer have spaces in their names ... very puzzling!

Answer (score 0):

Also, the event source cannot also be "Application", if you are logging in "Application" (Just FYI, for people figuring out event logging, as I was trying now. Not an answer). It would give the logging details as the following -

> The description for Event ID 101 from source Application cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Log message example
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table